# How do I send messages from a react app to my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to send session data in the form of a message from my React app to a chrome extension (MV3).  According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage), I should be using

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

However, doing so gives me the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`

Is there any way to resolve this? I've added `/*global chrome*/` at the top of my file which got rid of the `chrome undefined` error, but now it's runtime that's undefined.

manifest.json:

```
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab" , "scripting"],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
  "ids": ["extension_id"],
  "matches": ["http://localhost:3001/"]
},
```

App.js (of the react app):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const App = () => {

  function test() {
    const extensionId = 'extension_id';
    const session = "session";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, session,
          function(response) {
             console.log(response);     
          });
    }

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)


  const signInHandler = (event) => {
    test();
  }

  return ( 
      <div>
        <button onClick={signInHandler}>Sign in</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Listener in Background.js:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.session) {
            console.log(request);
        }
        sendResponse("OK");
});
```

Comment: There are several other required things, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage).

Comment: Other required thing such as? The documentation mentions specifying the url of the web page you want to listen from, and I've done that. The error is about chrome.runtime being undefined.

Comment: That's the same link I've added in the question (Sending messages from web pages). I have followed the instructions given there and still get the same error.

Comment: Strange... Can you try a simple html page without react to test sendMessage?

Comment: @JohanHoeksma I tried that, it gives me the same error `Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`. I thought of using `window.postMessage` but the content script does not seem to be a secure place for handling login session data.

Comment: @wOxxOm Please see the updated code. Right now, clicking on the Sign In button does not return the previous error, however, it does not log anything on to the console as should be expected.

Comment: Try removing `:3001` and adding `*` in manifest.json e.g. `http://localhost/*`. Don't forget to reload the extension and the web page afterwards.

Comment: I did so and reloaded both of them, it still does nothing. Is using `window.postMessage` a safe alternative? Please note that I'm passing user session to the extension once the user has logged in from the website.

Comment: Maybe your React app is running inside an iframe with a different dynamic URL?

Comment: I am not using iframes in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https instead of http, chrome.runtime api is only exposed to secured webpages.